# Mysql : duplicate last record every minute

Tags: php, mysql

I want to duplicate the last record in my table every minute, i'm using php and mysql.

I can use a cronjob to run it every minute, i know how to do that.

But i don't know how to duplicate the last row, i only have an id that auto_increment and value column.

For example :

```
Id, Value
10, Green
11, Green
12, Green
13, Green
```

Comment: `insert into table (value) select value from table order by id desc limit 1`

Comment: I'm curious as to why you think you need to be doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I think `select into` is what you are looking for.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: Please, whenever possible, link to the official documentation and not third-party sites like w3schools. Sites like w3schools are often wildly out of date and promote hazardous database practices.

Comment: @Kisraragi  Thank you ! I used your solution